# Uncatchable webview exception?

Tags: android

I want to clear all webview data from my app. I'm doing the following:

```
WebViewDatabase wvd = WebViewDatabase.getInstance(context);
if (wvd != null) {
    try { 
        wvd.clearUsernamePassword(); <-- throws an uncatchable exception
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "nope!", ex);
    }
}
```

The clearUsernamePassword() line throws an exception, and it's not being caught by the above try / catch:

```
native_execute (step): errno = 2, error message = No such file or directory, handle = 0x47ec78
clearUsernamePassword Storage full, abort doing SQLite operation.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: error code 10: disk I/O error
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1721)
  at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.clearUsernamePassword(WebViewDatabase.java:1278)
```

What are we supposed to do here?

Thanks

-------- Update ---------

Here's a link to the method that's causing it (it's not mine, it's part of android):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewDatabase.html#clearUsernamePassword()

I'm actually getting a few exceptions like this from different methods of WebViewDatabase (the app has lots of downloads thus the high volume I'm seeing. I actually was able to finally reproduce this on a device).

The above code is not being run on a separate thread.

Comment: Can you post your `clearUsernamePassword()` method?

Comment: nice one ! Is that due to native code ?

Comment: The only scenario I can imagine where you can't catch an `Exception` is if it's thrown in a different `Thread`. But neither the source nor the stacktrace look like there is one. That might be a bug in the android native code.

Comment: @user291701 Were you able to solve this exception? I am facing a similar crash.

Comment: @tarkeshwar: No I was not able to figure out what was going on. This crash continues to happen in my app.